# Cannot read property of push as undefined Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have an http service to get a stock symbol:

```
getStockBySymbol(symbol): Observable<IEXStockPrice> {
    return this.http.get<IEXStockPrice>(this.IEXBaseUrl + '/stock/' + symbol + '/quote');
}
```

in my component, I: 1) have a local variable of `watchlist: IEXStockPrice[];`
2) call my getStockbySymbol service and subscribe to it:

```
addStockToWatchList() {
    this.iex.getStockBySymbol(this.symbol)
      .subscribe(
        (data: IEXStockPrice) => {
          this.watchlist.push(data);
          this.alertify.success('Added ' + data.symbol);
          this.symbol = '';
        },
        (err: any) => {
          this.alertify.error('Could not add symbol to the watchlist');
          this.symbol = '';
        }
      );
  }
```

However, when I try to add the returned stock to the local watchlist array of stocks, I get a `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` in the console. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: change `watchlist: IEXStockPrice[];` to `watchlist: IEXStockPrice[] = [];`

Comment: thanks. that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declared your local variable but not initialized it:

```
watchlist: IEXStockPrice[] = [];
```

then you will be ok to go.

You need to initialize array before using array functions such as push, pop, etc.